# Can you use ControllerAs syntax within separate Controllers that share the same view?

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller, angularjs-controlleras

**QUESTION:**

Can you use ControllerAs syntax within separate Controllers that share the same view?

ie: (var vm = this)?

**DILEMMA**

I'm trying to get rid of the linter error in my console generated by EsLinter:

```
"Designated alias 'vm' is not assigned to 'this' consistent-this"
```

[image]

I would like to know how I can use : **var vm = this** within the controller or set the **Controller as vm** (I've tried both and it doesn't work)

The only thing that works is **$scope** within the controller (as seen below)... whenever I try to apply ***controller as syntax*** within the controller.js or the html div and apply the correlated variable (vm) to the interpolated expressions within the modal.html the data isn't rendered.

**What is best practice for this?**

** **SIDE NOTE:**
I'm also having issues binding the **ng-click action function** to the view based on controller... the below examples do not work (for the action)-- also if I change the {{::action}} to {{::action()}} the function fires on load and not on click:

**Example modal.html:**

```
<article>
    <h1>{{::title}}</h1>
    <p>{{::body}}</p>
    <button ng-click="{{::action}}">{{::button}}</button>
</article>
```

**HTML pulling in above ^**

```
<div class="hide"
     ng-controller="ConfirmModalController"
     ng-include src="'/app/widgets/modals/modal.html'"></div>

<div class="hide"
     ng-controller="ErrorModalController"
     ng-include src="'/app/widgets/modals/modal.html'"></div>
```

**Example Controllers**

*Error Controller*

```
angular
  .module('common.modal')
  .controller('ErrorModalController', ErrorModalController);

function ErrorModalController(modalService, $scope) {

  var vm = $scope;

  vm.title = 'There was an error with your request';

  vm.body = 'Please contact adminstrator regarding this error';

  vm.button = 'Dismiss';

  vm.action = function () {
    console.log("closing modals");
    modalService.closeAllModals();
  };

}
```

*Confirm Controller*

```
angular
  .module('common.modal')
  .controller('ConfirmModalController', ConfirmModalController);

function ConfirmModalController(modalService, $scope) {

  var vm = $scope;

  vm.title = 'Confirm Your Subscription';

  vm.body = '$8.99 per month will be billed to your account.';

  vm.button = 'Subscribe';

  vm.action = function () {
    console.log("confirming subscription");
    modalService.confirmSubscription();
  };

}
```

Comment: The template is not dynamic and it would make more sense to make it 2 directives instead of using ng-include.

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion @estus to create a directive for each type of modal - The data is now rendering correctly with vm=this ...

And thank you to @JC-Ford for telling me how to fix the {{::action}} to vm.action() with no brackets ...

** **SIDE NOTE: (still have the issue with the action button however)**

**Solution main.html**

```
<confirm-modal></confirm-modal>
```

**Solution modal.html:**

```
<article>
    <h1>{{::vm.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{::vm.body}}</p>
    <button ng-click="vm.action()">{{::vm.button}}</button>
</article>
```

**Solution confirm-modal.directive.js (and controller)**

```
angular
  .module('common.modal')
  .controller('ConfirmModalController', ConfirmModalController)
  .directive('confirmModal', confirmModal);

/* @ngInject */
function confirmModal() {

  var directive = {
    templateUrl: 'app/widgets/modals/modal.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: ConfirmModalController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };

  return directive;
}

function ConfirmModalController(modalService) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.title = 'Confirm Your Subscription';

  vm.body = '$8.99 per month will be billed to your account.';

  vm.button = 'Subscribe';

  vm.action = function () {
    modalService.confirmSubscription();
  };

}
```

**Solution error-modal.directive.js (and controller)**

```
angular
  .module('common.modal')
  .controller('ErrorModalController', ErrorModalController)
  .directive('errorModal', errorModal);

/* @ngInject */
function errorModal() {
  var directive = {
    templateUrl: 'app/widgets/modals/modal.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: ErrorModalController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };

  return directive;
}

function ErrorModalController(modalService) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.title = 'There was an error with your request';

  vm.body = 'Please contact administrator regarding this error';

  vm.button = 'Dismiss';

  vm.action = function () {
    modalService.closeAllModals();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data isn't rendered because you're not including the controller in the references. I don't see where you're loading the controller in your template, but if you're referrencing the controller using controllerAs syntax, then to reference its properties you have to use that reference. IOW, if you load your controller as foo, then your template should look like:

```
<article>
    <h1>{{::foo.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{::foo.body}}</p>
    <button ng-click="{{::foo.action()}}">{{::foo.button}}</button>
</article>
```

In the code you've posted, you're not using controllerAs syntax. You'd need to load it with  `ng-controller="ConfirmModalController as vm"`. There's no direct correlation between how you reference it in your JavaScript and in the template. You don't even have to call them the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually tried this and double checked just to make sure. It doesn't work. When I put in {{vm.button}} on the modal.html then within the controller assign var vm= this... then also on the rendered page where I'm pulling in the particular version of this template (via Controller) - (as shown above) - and say ng-controller="ConfirmModalController as vm" ... the data doesn't render still

Comment: Okay I get that they don't have to be the same ... yet the var vm = this or var foo = this .... is where I'm running into an issue... the only thing that works is when I apply that variable to $scope... var vm = $scope or var foo = $scope. I'm trying to get rid of the linter error in my console: " Designated alias 'vm' is not assigned to 'this'  consistent-this" << this is generated by the ES Linter

Comment: also if I change the {{::action}} to {{::action()}} the function fires on load and not on click

Comment: Unless you've changed your template, you're not using controllerAs.

Comment: You mean in the code above? I purposely didn't do that syntax within the <div> element because it still gives me the linter error. Then when I add the vm=this to the controller the data doesn't render.... so my code breaks. I put up above what currently works (minus the action button)... I'm just trying to get rid of the linter error. It currently acts correctly as I wrote it (besides the action button)...